# Netbeans: Copy the word where the caret/cursor is

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I create this keyboard shortcut in Netbeans?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open up Tools->Options->Editor

Create a new macro

Use this for the macro:

```
select-identifier copy-to-clipboard
```

Set up a shortcut for it, ah-la <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> and you can rock and roll.

Comment: and is there any, for just selecting(highlighting) the current word, if we are in the middle of it.